# Optimization in more than 1 variables

Tags: optimization

I have a function of x1, x2, x3 and x4 i.e. y=f(x1, x2, x3, x4). I do not know the exact functional form but I have 50+ different settings of x1, x2, x3 and x4 and the corresponding y values. I want to find, in r, the values of x1, x2, x3 and x4 that approximately minimize my function f(x1, x2, x3, x4).

Comment: The simplex method is what you want. Look up linear optimization.

Comment: Can you provide some more information perhaps even a context. Is r a set of values f(x1, x2, x3, x4) -> r? or x1,x2,x3,x4 are part of r?

Comment: by "r" I meant R-Language. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: x's are not affecting y linearly. I can see from the plot. Will the linear optimization still work?